# JQuery/JS Ajax function not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This problem has been killing me!

I have some jquery which will always throw this error to the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

from the line with the $.ajax() function call in it.

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    $("#form").submit();
});

$("#form").submit({
    $.ajax({
      url: "../php/mailForm.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:$("#form").serialize(),
      complete:function(){
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#subject').val("");
        $('#message').val("");
        $('#successMsg').removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is how I load both jquery and this javascript file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/contact.js"></script>
```

(in that order)

Does anyone have any clue as to what's going on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap them in a anonymous function `function(){}`, the same way you did for `.click()`:

```
$('#send').click(function(){
   $("#form").submit();
});
$("#form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "../php/mailForm.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:$("#form").serialize(),
      complete:function(){
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#subject').val("");
        $('#message').val("");
        $('#successMsg').removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

`.submit()` expects a function callback. So wrap your code inside an anonymous function.